# Schedule scrapy command scrapy crawl

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks, scrapy

I've built a crawler to crawl and extract links matching a fixed regex. Now i want to schedule the task in windows task scheduler, such that it executes the crawler using command line prompt `scrapy crawl crawlername`.  Any help would be useful?

Comment: This is a Windows question rather than a scrapy coding issue right? One for Super User perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bat file with the content:

```
cd path_to_scrapy_project
scrapy crawl crawlername
```

Then schedule this script with Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fil like `run.py`

and put your script like that example with multiple spiders :

````
import os
import logging

def crawl():
    os.system('scrapy crawl spider1')
    os.system('scrapy crawl spider2')
    os.system('scrapy crawl spider3')

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(crawl)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()```
````